# Error converting date time to smalldatetime

Tags: sql-server

I  had created 3 views in SQL server, the first and the second view have a small date time columns and the second one has date time, so in order to do union between the views I convert date time into a small date time using the function convert in SQL server like so:

```
Convert (SMALLDATETIME, V_date)
```

I had this error:

```
error in converting a varchar to smalldatetime
```

Note I used cast and always it is the same error. I don't understand why it gets me `varchar` in the error message because the column value (`V_date`) in the origin is datetime.

Comment: view 1: samll date time as 2016-04-12 00:00:00    View2 the same data , view3 is date time 2016-04-12 00:00:00.000 and i want to convert it into date time in the view3 it works. but when I doo union between the three views I had the message error bellow.

Comment: what if you CAST(field to DATETIME) when using any field

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error because V_date is `VARCHAR` and not `DATETIME`

you should check the content of your V_date field because it doesn't contains a valid date (check for MDY vs DMY)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

SELECT CONVERT(smalldatetime, CONVERT(datetime, V_date));

Comment: UNFORTUNALLY NO, it works in the view but when I do the UNION I get always the error message below

Comment: Works fine with me. Can you post complete query??

Comment: select code as dom, name as tiers , totalttc as ttc , totalht as ht, NuMbl       AS  Num, V_date as CONVERT(smalldatetime, CONVERT(datetime, V_date)) from Mb_views3

Comment: whats schema of Mb_views3 view? Can you post description here?

Answer (score 0):

Use try_convert and then look for NULLs in the output to locate invalid data.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT V_date as original, TRY_CONVERT(smalldatetime, TRY_CONVERT(datetime, V_date)) as d FROM yourtable) t
WHERE d IS NULL;
```